# I am trying to create a simple vertex ai pipeline to read a gcs folder containing .parquet files using kubeflow

Tags: pipeline, google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow

Error importing aiplatform

Tried following the vertex ai documentation and while running:

from google_cloud_pipeline_components import aiplatform as gcc_aip

I get an error:
Import error: Cannot import name '_dynamic' from 'kfp.components' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site_packages/kfp/components/**init**.py)

Answer (score 1):

One possible workaround is by using the v1 or v2 of [`kfp==2.0.0b16`](https://pypi.org/project/kfp/2.0.0b16/). You can upgrade your pip or install the said version of kfp.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install kfp==2.0.0b16
```